# how can I pass the value of html/php page to Python script

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have a very simple question ... I have a two input text field and a output text field in php page (index.php) and a multiply function code in Python (add.py).  Now I want to take the input from php page and calulate the result within python funtion and print the result on php output text field. I do not have any idea how to do it.

**index.php**

```php
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
    Input 1: <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $input1;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $inputErr;?></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    Input 2: <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $inputErr;?></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    Output:
    <textarea name="output" rows="5" cols="40">
        <?php echo $output;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

**multiply.py**

```py
number1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
number2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
mul = number1 * number2
print("Multiplication of given two numbers is: ", mul)
```

Comment: I would do it with selenium and xpaths.

Comment: Is the HTML + PHP page on your server? Why do you want the extra complication of interfacing with Python just to perform a simple multiplication?

Comment: LOL! You've got a script called `add` that multiplies two numbers. Something that PHP is also quite capable of doing by the way, so I'm assuming this is just an example. Secondly, it's a python script designed to handle command line input. Why do you want to build that, and then automate from a PHP script?

Comment: @BenHillier .. I have a python programme which works somethin like the above and Im trying to integrate with php. But still I dont understood how to call the script in php.

Comment: So what I understand from the later edits and comments is you just want to know how to call a python script from PHP? Then you need to look at the `exec` command. Something like `exec('python ./multiply.py', $result);`, but you also need to get that python script to accept values from the command line, like @bruno-desthuilliers described in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to change your python script so it can gets numbers from the commandline arguments instead of reading from stdin. You may also want to change the output so it only prints the result without other unrelated text:

```
# add.py
# NB : this should really be named 'multiply', not 'add'

import sys
try:
    number1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    number2 = int(sys.argv[2])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    sys.exit("usage: python add.py <number1> <number2>")

result = number1 * number2
print(result)
```

Then on the php side it's just a matter of [calling the script with `exec`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php) with the proper command string (you have to insert the numbers in the command string) and reading the result from the `$ouput` array.

This being said, one can only wonder why you want to call a Python script to do such a simple thing as a multiplication...

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually, I have a python programme which works somethin like the above and Im trying to integrate with php. But still I dont understood how to call the script in php.

Comment: @explorer104 what don't you understand in the doc I linked to ?